# Joining and Ordering two tables that have same columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to combine these two tables then order it by one column (`stamp`), and aliasing the second table's `id` field. I've tried joins, merges, but nothing seems to work. I am also trying to group them by the `mm`

Table `note`

```
  id | mm |   stamp    |
==========================
  1  | 5  | 2009-12-11 |
  2  | 33 | 2010-09-10 |
  3  | 22 | 2011-07-08 |
  4  | 1  | 2012-05-06 |
```

Table `note_admin`

```
  id | mm |   stamp    |
==========================
  1  | 5  | 2009-08-15 |
  2  | 5  | 2011-11-11 |
  3  | 5  | 2012-01-08 |
  4  | 35 | 2012-02-06 |
```

Query I thought would work:

```
(SELECT * FROM note WHERE mm=5)
UNION
(SELECT id AS a_id, mm, stamp FROM note_admin WHERE mm=5) 
ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

Expected Result

```
  id | a_id | mm |   stamp    |
================================
     |   3  | 5  | 2012-01-08 |
     |   2  | 5  | 2011-11-11 |
  1  |      | 5  | 2009-12-11 |
     |   1  | 5  | 2009-08-15 |
```

I don't even know if this is possible. I found a way to sort this in PHP but it would be much easier if it can be done in mySQL. Thanks.

Comment: field names must be the same. do SELECT * FROM in both ...

Comment: @Glavić the opposite -- _never_ do `SELECT *` in a `UNION` query. Always be explicit about the column order!

Comment: if tables are the same, no need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this, note the same 4 column names (not sure about the order by though):

```
(SELECT a_id as NULL, note.* FROM note WHERE mm=5) UNION (SELECT id AS a_id, NULL as id, mm, stamp FROM note_admin WHERE mm=5) ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

Comment: this seemed to work:
(SELECT null as a_id, id, mm, stamp FROM note WHERE mm=5) UNION (SELECT id AS a_id, NULL as id, mm, stamp FROM note_admin WHERE mm=5) ORDER BY stamp DESC

Comment: `ORDER BY` is ok. MySQL manual says: To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.